# How send this data

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm terribly lost. I have to do a webhook in order to catch the informations enter by the user in a Formidable forms (in WordPress).

I make, with the help of stackoverflow, a JQUERY script to retrieve the input informations (name of the input, and label). This script create an array before submitting the form.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    var itemMetaArray = {};

    $('.frm_pro_form :input:not(:hidden, :submit)').each(function() {
        var label = $(this).closest('.frm_form_field').find('label').text().trim();
        itemMetaArray[label] = $(this).attr('name');
    });

    console.log(itemMetaArray);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: { itemMetaArray: itemMetaArray},
        success: function(){
            console.log('Success');
        }
    });
});
```

Now my problem is : How I can process the forms data in a distant php script after form submitting ?

The array created by JQUERY will help me for processing data, in order to know which input is related with what ? (the name of the inputs are disgusting, and I can't modify them)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what you want but you can convert this array into json and send to the php script, then decode it.

Comment: How can I send it ?

Comment: `itemMetaArray` is an object so just pass that. jQuery will do the POST conversion for you

Comment: you mean how can i process with jquery ? or in a "traditional" form submitting ?

Comment: In your `index.php` file, in this case, you can *catch* the data like so: `$_POST['itemMetaArray`];`. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

for AJAX with Wordpress, you should follow the codex at https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins.

Briefly, you need to do three things:
1) Define a callback function in PHP to handle the AJAX request
2) Add a variable named 'action' to the 'data' field in your AJAX request.
3) Add two actions in your plugin or in the functions.php file as shown below.  The first parameter should be wp_ajax_[name of action] and wp_ajax_nopriv_[name of action].  The second parameter should be the name of the callback function from step 1.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

There are other guidelines to follow for the callback function.  Refer to the codex for those.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply access it by-

```
$labelname1=$_POST['itemMetaArray']['label1'];
$labelname2=$_POST['itemMetaArray']['label2'];
```

Comment: I found the problem, the POST data aren't update in the index.php page. But in the developper tools, under network tab then response I can see the POST data :)